# backup postgresql desde java

Tags: java, postgresql

Tengo un código implementado para hace el backup pero cuando se ejecuta no me hace nada y tampoco da ningún error he buscado en Internet otras maneras de hacerlo pero todos los ejemplos son parecidos al código que uso(ademas los probé y tampoco me funcionan) :

```
    Process p;
    ProcessBuilder pb;        
    pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dump.exe",
        "--host", "localhost",
        "--port", "5432",
        "--username", "postgres",
        "--no-password",
        "--format", "custom",
        "--blobs",
        "--verbose", "--file", "D:\\bd.backup", "r4_citmatel_2016");
    p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Tus credenciales deben llevar el signo de `=`, por ejemplo, fíjate como se escribe el `host`, `port`, `username`, etc.  `pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dumpall.exe",
        "--host=localhost",
        "--port=5432",
        "--username=postgres",
        "--no-password",
        "--format=custom",
        "--blobs",
        "--verbose", "--file=D:\\mi_backup.backup", "r4_citmatel_2016");` Para depurar puedes valerte del método  [getErrorStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--)

Comment: Pues, para empezar no estás _imprimiendo_ la salida del comando. ¿Ya probaste el comando en el Símbolo de Sistema? No _te_ hace nada porque tal vez algo [es-ta-mal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamal). Agrega `inheritIO()` (si es que estás usando Java 7 o superior) para que veas la salida en Java. `rt` no es necesario aquí si es que estás usando `ProcessBuilder`. Bueno, seguro son las reliquias de tanto _copy&paste_.

Comment: "no me hace nada y tampoco da ningún error "
Perdón pero eso no lo creo. Prueba correr con ProcessBuilder un programa _cualquiera_ pasando argumentos que le hagan tirar un error, y fijate si sabes capturar y mostrar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aca mi paso a paso de como `respaldo` y `restauro` mi base de datos `Postgresql` desde `Java`.

```
import java.io.File;

public class BaseDatos extends Conexionbd{

    private Process proceso;
    private ProcessBuilder constructor;

    private final String host = "localhost";
    private final String puerto="5432";
    private final String usuario = "postgres";
    private final String clave = "root";
    private final String bd="siceo";
    private final String formato="custom";

    public boolean BD_backup(String path){
        boolean hecho=false;
        try{
            File pgdump= new File("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\\pg_dump.exe");
            if(pgdump.exists()){
                if(!path.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    constructor = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\\pg_dump.exe", "--verbose", "--format", formato, "-f", path);
                } else {                             
                    constructor = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\\pg_dump.exe", "--verbose", "--inserts", "--column-inserts", "-f", path);
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
                constructor.environment().put("PGHOST", host);
                constructor.environment().put("PGPORT", puerto);
                constructor.environment().put("PGUSER", usuario);
                constructor.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", clave);
                constructor.environment().put("PGDATABASE", bd);
                constructor.redirectErrorStream(true);
                proceso= constructor.start();
                escribirProcess(proceso);
                System.out.println("terminado backup " + path);
                hecho=true;
            }else{
                if(!path.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    constructor = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_dump", "--verbose", "--format", formato, "-f", path);
                } else {                             
                    constructor = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_dump", "--verbose", "--inserts", "--column-inserts", "-f", path);
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
                constructor.environment().put("PGHOST", host);
                constructor.environment().put("PGPORT", puerto);
                constructor.environment().put("PGUSER", usuario);
                constructor.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", clave);
                constructor.environment().put("PGDATABASE", bd);
                constructor.redirectErrorStream(true);
                proceso= constructor.start();
                escribirProcess(proceso);
                System.out.println("terminado backup " + path);
                hecho=true;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage()+ "Error de backup");
            hecho=false;
        }
        return hecho;
    }


    public boolean restaurarBackup(String path) {
        boolean hecho=false;
        try {
            File pgrestore = new File("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\\pg_restore.exe");
            if(pgrestore.exists()){
                constructor = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\\pg_restore.exe", "-i", "-h", host, "-p", puerto, "-U", usuario, "-d", bd, "-v", path);
                constructor.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", clave);
                constructor.redirectErrorStream(true);
                proceso=constructor.start();
                escribirProcess(proceso);
                hecho=true;
            }else{
                constructor = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_restore", "-i", "-h", host, "-p", puerto, "-U", usuario, "-d", bd, "-v", path);
                constructor.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", clave);
                constructor.redirectErrorStream(true);
                proceso=constructor.start();
                escribirProcess(proceso);
                hecho=true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            hecho=false;
        }
        return hecho;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para psql necesitas un signo igual "=". Por lo que debe ser, por ejemplo --host=localhost. Para que usted necesita para pasar esos argumentos como una sola cadena de argumentos para ProcessBuilder:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\bin\\pg_dump.exe",
        "--host=localhost",
        "--port=5432",
        "--username=postgres",
        "--no-password",
        "--format=custom",
        "--blobs",
        "--verbose", "--file=D:\\bd.backup", "r4_citmatel_2016");
```

Capturar la salida de error del ProcessBuilder utilizar ProcessBuilder.getErrorStream()para ver cualquier mensaje de error psql.